# Can I install MS SQL Server Express 2008 on the same box as MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, sql-server-2005

I am a developer and I wanted to ensure that I have a full MS SQL Server at my disposal if need  be.

Can I also install MS SQL Express 2008 on the same box, so I can do small dev projects using SQLExpress instead of MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You will need to install them as Named Instances (say \SQLEXPRESS and \SQL2k8) but they will work just fine.

Comment: You can install SQL Server as the default instance, then any other install as a named instance. All Express installs are named instances and I don't think there is a limit on how many you can install (express or otherwise). It would be available resources that would define this upper limit. Also if you install SQL Server full version, that management studio can be used to administrate your express versions

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, sql express will install as a named instance.  However you can also install up to 16 instances of the full sql server (standard) on the same box.  There is no development diference between sql server express and standard.  The list of features supported by edition is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).  I would probably reccomend sticking with just the full SQL server to cut down on system administration headaches as the express edition service packs are usuallly different than the sql ones (althought they provide the same functionality)

Comment: Jim B: Voted you up since the information on minimizing admin overhead is very helpful. Thanks.